# Connection refused on socket implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I've tried out a code that I found in a book but I'm not able to run it.
In fact, the error that this code is raising is: **[Errno 111] Connection refused** when the `run_client` function runs the line `with socket.create_connection(address) as connection`. Would anybody know the cause?

The code is the following:

```
class EOFError(Exception):
    pass

class ConnectionBase:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.file = connection.makefile('rb')

    def send(self, command):
        line = command + '\n'
        data = line.encode()
        self.connection.send(data)

    def receive(self):
        line = self.file.readline()
        if not line:
            raise EOFError('Connection closed')
        return line[:-1].decode()

import random

WARMER = 'Warmer'
COLDER = 'Colder'
UNSURE = 'Unsure'
CORRECT = 'Correct'

class UnknowCommandError(Exception):
    pass

class Session(ConnectionBase):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._clear_state(None, None)

    def _clear_state(self, lower, upper):
        self.lower = lower
        self.upper = upper
        self.secret = None
        self.guesses = []

    def loop(self):
        while command := self.receive():
            match parts := command.split():
                case ['PARAM', lower, upper]:
                    self.set_params(lower, upper)
                case ['NUMBER', *_]:
                    self.send_number()
                case ['REPORT', decision]:
                    self.receive_report(decision)
                case _:
                    raise UnknowCommandError(command)

    def set_params(self, lower, upper):
        self._clear_state(lower, upper)

    def next_guess(self):
        if self.secret is not None:
            return self.secret

        while True:
            guess = random.randint(self.lower, self.upper)
            if guess not in self.guesses:
                return guess

    def send_number(self):
        guess = self.next_guess()
        self.guesses.append(guess)
        self.send(format(guess))

    def receive_report(self, decision):
        last = self.guesses[-1]

        if decision == CORRECT:
            self.secret = last

        print(f'Server: {last} is {decision}')

import contextlib
import math

class Client(ConnectionBase):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._clear_state()

    def _clear_state(self):
        self.secret = None
        self.last_distance = None

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def session(self, lower, upper, secret):
        print(f'Guess a number between {lower} and {upper}!'
              f'Shhhhhh, it is {secret}.')
        self.secret = secret
        self.send('PARAM {lower} {upper}')
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            self._clear_state()
            self.send('PARAM 0 -1')

    def request_numbers(self, count):
        for _ in range(count):
            self.send('NUMBER')
            data = self.receive()
            yield int(data)
            if self.last_distance == 0:
                return

    def report_outcome(self, number):
        new_distance = math.fabs(number - self.secret)
        decision = UNSURE

        if new_distance == 0:
            decision = CORRECT
        elif self.last_distance is None:
            pass
        elif new_distance < self.last_distance:
            decision = WARMER
        elif new_distance > self.last_distance:
            decision = COLDER

        self.last_distance = new_distance

        self.send(f'REPORT {desicion}')
        return decision


import socket
from threading import Thread

def handle_connection(connection):
    with connection:
        session = Session(connection)
        try:
            session.loop()
        except EOFError:
            pass

def run_server(address):
    with socket.socket() as listener:
        listener.bind(address)
        listener.listen()
        while True:
            connection, _ = listener.accept()
            thread = Thread(target=handle_connection,
                            args=(connection,),
                            daemon=True)
            thread.start()

def run_client(address):
    with socket.create_connection(address) as connection:
        client = Client(connection)

        with client.session(1, 5, 3):
            results = [(x, client.report_outcome(x))
                      for x in client.request_numbers(5)]

        with client.session(10, 15, 12):
            for number in client.request_numbers(5):
                outcome = client.report_outcome(number)
                results.append((number, outcome))

    return results

def main():
    address = ('127.0.0.1', 1234)
    server_thread = Thread(target=run_server,
                           args=(address,),
                           daemon=True)
    server_thread.start()

    results = run_client(address)
    for number, outcome in results:
        print(f'Client: {number} is {outcome}')

main()
```

This code intends to create a TCP-based server for playing a game involving guessing a number. The server takes *lower* and *upper* parameters that determine the range of the numbers to consider. Then, the server returns guesses for integer values in that range as they are requested by the client. Finally, the server collects reports from the client on whether each of those numbers was closer (warmer) or further away (colder) from the client's secret number.

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to the part that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It simply means that the code cannot connect to the given address. Maybe there is no server processing listening on this address in the first place. Hard to know what you are trying to achieve and what you do, because basically you post an undocumented code dump without further explanation. Maybe read the book where you've found this in more detail to understand how this code should be used.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sure! I've just added some documentation about it. The book is Effective Python from Brett Slatkin. I went several time through this chapter but I cannot find out what's wrong in my implementation.

Comment: @tul1: First, your code is using the `match` statement from the not yet released version 3.10 of Python, which is a bad idea if you want others to reproduce your problem (the original code does not). Also, you should get more than just this short error you include, so please include the full error message with the full stacktrace in your question. But in short: one typo and one `'...'` instead of `f'...'` where the latter messes up the exchanged messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to have been a typo somewhere, I've corrected it. Thank you for you help @SteffenUllrich

this is the working code:

```
class EOFError(Exception):
    pass

class ConnectionBase:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
        self.file = connection.makefile('rb')

    def send(self, command):
        line = command + '\n'
        data = line.encode()
        self.connection.send(data)

    def receive(self):
        line = self.file.readline()
        if not line:
            raise EOFError('Connection closed')
        return line[:-1].decode()

import random

WARMER = 'Warmer'
COLDER = 'Colder'
UNSURE = 'Unsure'
CORRECT = 'Correct'

class UnknowCommandError(Exception):
    pass

class Session(ConnectionBase):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._clear_state(None, None)

    def _clear_state(self, lower, upper):
        self.lower = lower
        self.upper = upper
        self.secret = None
        self.guesses = []

    def loop(self):
        while command := self.receive():
            match command.split():
                case ['PARAM', lower, upper]:
                    self.set_params(int(lower), int(upper))
                case ['NUMBER', *_]:
                    self.send_number()
                case ['REPORT', decision]:
                    self.receive_report(decision)
                case _:
                    raise UnknowCommandError(command)

    def set_params(self, lower, upper):
        self._clear_state(lower, upper)

    def next_guess(self):
        if self.secret is not None:
            return self.secret

        while True:
            guess = random.randint(self.lower, self.upper)
            if guess not in self.guesses:
                return guess

    def send_number(self):
        guess = self.next_guess()
        self.guesses.append(guess)
        self.send(format(guess))

    def receive_report(self, decision):
        last = self.guesses[-1]
        if decision == CORRECT:
            self.secret = last

        print(f'Server: {last} is {decision}')

import contextlib
import math

class Client(ConnectionBase):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._clear_state()

    def _clear_state(self):
        self.secret = None
        self.last_distance = None

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def session(self, lower, upper, secret):
        print(f'Guess a number between {lower} and {upper}!'
              f'Shhhhhh, it is {secret}.')
        self.secret = secret
        self.send(f'PARAM {lower} {upper}')
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            self._clear_state()
            self.send('PARAM 0 -1')

    def request_numbers(self, count):
        for _ in range(count):
            self.send('NUMBER')
            data = self.receive()
            yield int(data)
            if self.last_distance == 0:
                return

    def report_outcome(self, number):
        new_distance = math.fabs(number - self.secret)
        decision = UNSURE

        if new_distance == 0:
            decision = CORRECT
        elif self.last_distance is None:
            pass
        elif new_distance < self.last_distance:
            decision = WARMER
        elif new_distance > self.last_distance:
            decision = COLDER

        self.last_distance = new_distance

        self.send(f'REPORT {decision}')
        return decision


import socket
from threading import Thread

def handle_connection(connection):
    with connection:
        session = Session(connection)
        try:
            session.loop()
        except EOFError:
            pass

def run_server(address):
    with socket.socket() as listener:
        listener.bind(address)
        listener.listen()
        while True:
            connection, _ = listener.accept()
            thread = Thread(target=handle_connection,
                            args=(connection,),
                            daemon=True)
            thread.start()

def run_client(address):
    with socket.create_connection(address) as connection:
        client = Client(connection)

        with client.session(1, 5, 3):
            results = [(x, client.report_outcome(x))
                      for x in client.request_numbers(5)]

        with client.session(10, 15, 12):
            for number in client.request_numbers(5):
                outcome = client.report_outcome(number)
                results.append((number, outcome))

    return results

def main():
    address = ('127.0.0.1', 1234)
    server_thread = Thread(target=run_server,
                           args=(address,),
                           daemon=True)
    server_thread.start()

    results = run_client(address)
    for number, outcome in results:
        print(f'Client: {number} is {outcome}')


main()
```

PS0: to make it work you'll need python3.10 or change the functions in `loop`, `set_params` and `receive_report`.
PS1: Before, running the code make sure port `tcp:1234` of localhost is not in use.